# C# Getting a Form method into a User Control C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, streamreader, streamwriter

I am preparing for my 1st year test and one of the questions I know about is "Create a user control with a textBox and a button, and on form create a listBox" Okay. Now what has to happen is the listBox lists files from a dir. and the textBox in User Control reads the contents of this file(.txt) and the user is allowed to edit the text box, and the save button when click must then overwrite the original file. Now I got the whole textBox reading going using StreamReader. But I can't get the Button in the User Control to get the dir path from the ListBox.

I have to overwrite it using StreamWriter, can't use the FileDialog. It has to get the file name from the ListBox, and then that gets loaded into the StreamWriter dir path which needs to be in btnSave which lies in the UserControl.

I tried doing the vice versa with the userControl `userControl1.Text` property with a property I made. Then tried to call it like the userControl from the Form `Form1.ItemsName` but didn't work so I scraped that. Now Im having complete coders block.

And Im stumped. I have tried every thing to get the btnSave in the userControl to be able to get the data from the Form `listBox.SelectedItem.Text`

Form consists of: listBox and UserControl

userControl consists of: textBox and Button(btnSave).

Form1 code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reads the content from the file, 
        //listing other files in dir.

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\C# Resources\Numbers.txt");
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            // Adds content from Numbers.txt into the ListBox
            while (line != null)
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(line);

                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception Exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Exc.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            sr.Close();
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reads the name of the file in the list box, looking for the file in the dir.
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\C# Resources\" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");
        string all = file.ReadToEnd();

        //Loads the ListBox_click file's content into the userControl textBox
        userControl11.Text = all.ToString();
    }
}
```

UserControl code:

```
    // Creates method so the it can be loaded into form
    public string Text
    {
        set
        {
            textBox2.Text = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return textBox2.Text;
        }
    }

    //Has to overwrite/Save the content changed by the user in TextBox to the same 
    //directory/file it came from.

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\C# Resources\" + /*Method to get the file path from the Form1 ListBox*/ + ".txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the [FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx) Class.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a assignment/project work, i will just point you in the right direction.

- Add a property to user control like `public string FileToWrite {get; set;}`
- Then access the `FileToWrite` which will be the path to write.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileToWrite);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. But this is not a project or any related class work. This is self training. There was talk of a similar question so Im not cheating or anything (Wont help me in life, if i cheat through class anyway). Our textbooks never focused on user control. The problem is not creating a set or get. The problem lies when I have to call ListBox.SelectedItem.Text from the Form, into the btnSave which lies in the userControl. I know how to call user control to the Form 'userControl1.<whatever>' but I don't know how to call from Form to userControl. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't (or shouldn't) call form code from with the user control. You need another mechanism, either the form should let the control know the selected item at all times, or the user control should request the information.

Both of these can be done using events